# If $A$, $B$ are $3\times 3$ matrices, and all elements are different from each other and greater in their absolute value than 3, then is $AB \ne 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two $3\times 3$ matrices. All entries of $A$ are distinct and all entries of $B$ are distinct. All entries in both matrices are greater in their absolute value than 3. Then $AB \ne 0$.

Is this true or false, and why?

Comment: any idea, have you tried to check it by an example? The underlying field is $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: not necessarily $R$. didn't find examples, it's too complicated

Comment: so we can take any ring?

Comment: @dREaM oh you mean like $Z_5$ etc? that's ok

Comment: You have eighteen unknowns-the elements of $A$ and $B$.  You have nine equations, one for each element of $AB$.  You should have a nine dimensional solution space.  You need to make sure the determinant of each is zero.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\begin{pmatrix}  4 & 8 & 12 \\ 5 & 10 & 15 \\ 7 & 14 & 21 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}  -28 & -35 & -49 \\ 8 & 10 & 14 \\ 4 & 5 & 7 \end{pmatrix} 
=
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

The idea was to start with

$$\begin{pmatrix}  1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}  -7 & -7 & -7 \\ 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
and then experiment multiplying rows and columns respectively by  constants  until the elements in each respective matrix is distinct. You can read of those constants from the first column and last row: $4, 5, 7$.

Comment: +1 for explaining the though process involved.

Comment: but there's a 3. and "All entries in both matrices are greater in their absolute value than 3". Is this still possible?

Comment: I misread that. I thought they had to be greater than or equal to 3. Will fix. One minute.

Comment: @user3697301 multiply all entries of the second matrix by $\pi$, since $\pi \cdot 0 = 0$ and $A(\pi B) = \pi AB$ it should do the trick :).

Comment: @user3697301 just multiply everything with 2

Comment: @SimonS in your edit you have again two 4..

Comment: @Surb I guess that's fine, the distinct values are for each matrix, at least that's the sound of the question

Comment: That's how I read the question: the entries in each matrix are distinct; not that all entries in both matrices are distinct. In any case: if the latter is the correct reading, then it's easily fixed by multiplying one of the matrices by some other constant.

Comment: It's ok that A has 8 and B has 8. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: think of $AB$ in terms of row and column spaces. What does it mean for $(AB)_{11}$ to be $0$ in terms of the rows of $A$ and columns of $B$?

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick.